# How can I make a usable copy of an SQL Server database on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2003, sql-server

I need to make a usable copy of an SQL Server database on Windows Server 2003 for testing purposes. There is a backup tool built into Enterprise Manager but I can't seem to make it work.

I've tried "Right-click on database -> All Tasks -> Add... -> Enter a new name D:\Whatever\ ***20110803.bak*** -> OK

but got the message

> **Microsoft SQL-DMO (OCBD SQLSTATE:42000)**
>
> The volume on device "D:\whatever\ ***preexistant.bak*** is not part of a multiple
>   family media set. BACKUP WITH FORMAT can be used to form a new media
>   set.
>
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally
>   | OK

**Q**: What is a multiple family media set and why do I need the old existing backup file to be a multiple family media set if I'm creating a new backup?

**Q**: What is BACKUP WITH FORMAT? I'm pretty sure I don't want to format anything. Again, I'm trying to create a new backup file.

I click OK and see that a new destination has appeared in the Destination list, so I Select it and click OK.

I get the following message:

> **Microsoft SQL-DMO (ODBC SQLState: 42000)**
>
> Cannot open backup device "D:\whatever\ ***preexistant.bak***. Device error or device off-line. See the SQL Server error log for more details.
>
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally. | OK

**Q**: Wherer are whese error logs?

Comment: Can you take it off line?

Comment: Probably should go to SF.

Comment: Yes I can "Detach" it and copy the ".mdf" file. Doest that copy everything ? (users, groups, permissions, configuration, etc). Or are you saying I should make a backup while the database is detached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just detach it, and copy both the .mdf and .ldf to a new location. I do that all the time. When it is detached, they are just like regular files. I do it this way because it is A LOT faster.

If I can't take it off-line, I usually just use my backup software (Backup Exec usually) to make a new copy by redirecting the restore to a new location (MAKE SURE YOU DO NOT OVERWRITE THE ORIGINAL LOCATION).

Comment: Why do you also copy the .ldf file? What does it do?

Comment: @Shawn It is the transaction file...In other words, anything that has changed, but has not been committed to the database. You can probably do it without that, but I am just used to copying both to a new location, and then re-attaching.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than explaining the UI, it is probably easier to just open a query window and use SQL:

```
    backup database DatabaseName
    to disk = 'path-of-backup=file'
    with format, name='backup-name', copy_only
```

To restore to new DB:

- Right click on the databases node in SQL Management Studio's Object Explorer and select Restore.
- Enter the name of the new database in the "To database"
- Select "From Device" and use the "..." button to add the backup file and return to main dialogue.
- Select the backup to restore from in the list box (probably only one)

If you need to do this often, I would use the "script" option on the restore dialogue to generate the SQL, which is much quicker to re-use.